# Frequently checking NSF website for new grant?

Tags: funding, nsf

Shall one frequently check the NSF website for newly released grant opportunities?

How often does NSF release a new grant in fields like Machine Learning or Deep Learning? Per Month? Per half a year?

Comment: You can get on NSF's mailing list for new grant solicitations...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to stay up to date with NSF grants opportunities or any grant opportunities is to sign up for email alerts or for the funder's RSS feed. Both of these options are available for the NSF. See: https://beta.nsf.gov/funding/opportunities to the right above the search bar. Additionally there are for-pay grant/funding alert systems that your university may subscribe to. Do get in touch with your funding support office for more information about using those.

Comment: Thanks! That helps!